# Populate dataframe by row number

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

**Question**

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
d = {
'a': [['a', 0], ['b', 1], ['a', 2]],
'b': [['d', 0], ['d', 1], ['d', 3]],
'c': [['f', 2], ['g', 3], ['h', 4]]
}
```

The dictionary is of the form: `column: [[value, row_number], ... ]`

I'd like to transform this into a dataframe that looks like this:

```
      a     b     c
0     a     d  None
1     b     d  None
2     a  None     f
3  None     d     g
4  None  None     h
```

**Attempt**

The only way I can think to do this is to create a new dictionary of the form:

```
new = {
'a': ['a', 'b', 'a', None, None],
'b': ['d', 'd', None, 'd', None],
'c': [None, None, 'f', 'g', 'h']
}
```

And then this dictionary could be used to create the dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(new)
```

I could write a loop to do this but it's rather tedious and I'm wondering if there is a better way. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your dict is the way to go, but here is another solution

```
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
df1=pd.concat([df[x].apply(pd.Series).set_index(1) for x in df.columns],1)
df1.columns=df.columns
df1
Out[477]: 
     a    b    c
1               
0    a    d  NaN
1    b    d  NaN
2    a  NaN    f
3  NaN    d    g
4  NaN  NaN    h
```

If you would like change your dict

```
d1={k:{t[1]:t[0] for t in v} for k,v in d.items()}
d1
Out[479]: 
{'a': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'a'},
 'b': {0: 'd', 1: 'd', 3: 'd'},
 'c': {2: 'f', 3: 'g', 4: 'h'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think putting this straight into `pandas` will provide that significant of a speedup, as you'll be working with objects. Thus, it would be best to modify the dictionary of lists outside of `pandas`. The best way to do this would be to convert each list into a dictionary, as `pandas` is perfectly fine converting a `dict` of `dict`s into a `DataFrame`:

```
In [ ]: new_d = {col_name:{row_num: value for value, row_num in col_data} for col_name, col_data in d.items()}
   ...: pd.DataFrame(new_d)
Out[ ]: 
     a    b    c
0    a    d  NaN
1    b    d  NaN
2    a  NaN    f
3  NaN    d    g
4  NaN  NaN    h
```

Answer (score 0):

Restructure the dictionary as follows:

```
d2 = {colname: {sublist[1]: sublist[0] for sublist in listoflists} \
      for colname, listoflists in d.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame(d2)
df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)  # replace np.nan with None
     a    b    c
0    a    d  None
1    b    d  None
2    a  None    f
3  None    d    g
4  None  None    h
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot()`, after a bit of rearranging:

```
data = [(key,ix,val) for key, pair in d.items() for val, ix in pair]
df = pd.DataFrame(data).pivot(index=1, columns=0, values=2)
```

Output:

```
0     a     b     c
1                  
0     a     d  None
1     b     d  None
2     a  None     f
3  None     d     g
4  None  None     h
```

Note: To remove the column and index values, use:

```
df.index.name = ""
df.columns.name = ""
```